# How to query the first 10 time series before certain timestamp in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I want to query the first ten time series results before certain timestamp in Apache IoTDB. How should I write my sql query statement in IoTDB? I tried `order by time desc limit 10`, but seems like the results did not came back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `where time < now() order by time desc limit 10` command after the root name you want to check in Apache IoTDB.